# Convert square image to rectangle

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, gd

I want to convert a `1200x1200` image to `1200x600`.

But, I don't want to lose the image proportions and that's why I want to add a white border to the left and the right and have the image in the middle.

The final image will be like border at left and right and square image in middle, then I will save it to folder and user it in my project.

Is this possible using the GD library?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own mathematical function to display an image in a canvas of particular dimension. Here's a mathematical function that I use,

```
function resize_image($img,$maxwidth,$maxheight) {
    //This function will return the specified dimension(width,height)
    //dimension[0] - width
    //dimension[1] - height

    $dimension = array();
    $imginfo = getimagesize($img);
    $imgwidth = $imginfo[0];
    $imgheight = $imginfo[1];
    if($imgwidth > $maxwidth){
        $ratio = $maxwidth/$imgwidth;
        $newwidth = round($imgwidth*$ratio);
        $newheight = round($imgheight*$ratio);
        if($newheight > $maxheight){
            $ratio = $maxheight/$newheight;
            $dimension[] = round($newwidth*$ratio);
            $dimension[] = round($newheight*$ratio);
            return $dimension;
        }else{
            $dimension[] = $newwidth;
            $dimension[] = $newheight;
            return $dimension;
        }
    }elseif($imgheight > $maxheight){
        $ratio = $maxheight/$imgheight;
        $newwidth = round($imgwidth*$ratio);
        $newheight = round($imgheight*$ratio);
        if($newwidth > $maxwidth){
            $ratio = $maxwidth/$newwidth;
            $dimension[] = round($newwidth*$ratio);
            $dimension[] = round($newheight*$ratio);
            return $dimension;
        }else{
            $dimension[] = $newwidth;
            $dimension[] = $newheight;
            return $dimension;
        }
    }else{
        $dimension[] = $imgwidth;
        $dimension[] = $imgheight;
        return $dimension;
    }
}
```

Suppose you image size is 1200x1200(height:1200, width:1200) and your canvas size(where you want to display the image) is 1200x600(height:1200, width:600), you can call this *resize_image* function like this,

```
$dimension = resize_image("{$your_image_path}.jpg",600,1200);
$width = $dimension[0];
$height = $dimension[1];
```

and after getting the appropriate dimensions, display your image like this,

```
<img src="your_image_path.jpg" alt="Image" height="<?php echo $height; ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" />
```